# How to include css files in Vue 2

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to vue js and trying to learn this. I installed a fresh new version of vue webpack in my system. I'm having a css, js and images of this a theme template which I want to include into the HTML so i tried adding it in `index.html` but I can see errors in console and the assets are not being added. While I searched I came to know that I can use `require` in `main.js` file. But I'm getting the error:

Following I've tried in my `main.js` file:

```js
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import App from './App'
 import router from './router'

 require('./assets/styles/vendor.css');
 require('./assets/styles/main.css');
 require('./assets/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js');

 Vue.config.productionTip = false

 /* eslint-disable no-new */
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
 })
```

While I tried using import to use it but still I got error

```js
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import App from './App'
 import router from './router'

 import('./assets/styles/vendor.css')
 // require('./assets/styles/vendor.css');
 // require('./assets/styles/main.css');
 // require('./assets/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js');

 Vue.config.productionTip = false

 /* eslint-disable no-new */
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
 })
```

Here is the error screenshot:
[image: Error message]

Help me out in this.

Comment: Where did you install vue webpack from? Where did the theme template come from? And what editor is that you're using ?

Comment: @user1585345 I installed vue through `vue-cli` we are having a `html template` which have stylesheets in css files. and I'm working on `WebStorm` editor

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You can import the css file on App.vue, inside the style tag.

```html
<style>
  @import './assets/styles/yourstyles.css';
</style>
```

Also, make sure you have the right loaders installed, if you need any.

Comment: This works perfectly. I had also made it work importing styles in `index.js` file like this: `import '@/assets/css/styles.css`. Production generated css file appears to be the same. I wonder what solution is better...

Comment: If you import the css inside a style tag in a .vue, you can make it scoped and only apply the styles in the specific component. That's one different thing you can do, but I'm also not quite sure about which solution better.

Comment: @Bsienn did it say what dependency? Could be a loader.

Comment: @GeraldineGolong Hi, Thanks for reply, Sorry for not mentioning before, It was path issue, i needed to use `@` sign before source and it worked. using vue-clie v3.

Comment: @GeraldineGolong Hi, Thanks for reply, Sorry for not mentioning before, It was path issue, i needed to use @ sign before source and it worked. using vue-clie v3.

Comment: @gedii just had to say, this fix made my morning!! wanted to share the love

Comment: @ToddT You're welcome! Now you made MY day, I'm having a pretty tough one lol

Comment: This code does not scoped the css file. It will be share/accessible by all components

Comment: I had to change it to  ... @import url("https://....css"); ... to make it works

Comment: What if you are importing Vue from a CDN? How do you do scoped styles then?

Answer (score 51):

Try using the `@` symbol before the url string. Import your css in the following manner:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

require('@/assets/styles/main.css')
```

In your App.vue file you can do this to import a css file in the style tag

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped src="@/assets/styles/mystyles.css">
</style>
```

Comment: where does the require('...') go? Is it in the component file or in main.js or app.vue? There is import Vue from 'vue' in main.js Thanks

Comment: The require('...') goes to your main.js file. Remember those are you 'main.css' styles. Meaning styles you would wish to be used anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the only solution that scoped actually worked. In others it was transcending the component and breaking my layout

Answer (score 13):

You can import CSS file on component inside script tag

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
import "@/assets/<file-name>.css";

export default {}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

**main.js**

```
import "./assets/css/style.css"
```

**style.css** -- you can import multiple files.

```
@import './dev.css';
body{
    color: red
}
```

**dev.css**

```
body{
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to append this `css` file to `header` you can do it using `mounted()` function of the vue file. See the example.
**Note:** Assume you can access the `css` file as `http://www.yoursite/assets/styles/vendor.css` in the browser.

```
mounted() {
        let style = document.createElement('link');
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.href = '/assets/styles/vendor.css';
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of including a css file in your vue app. The way I prefer is to have a single css file import inside the main.js file for your vue app.

You can have multiple scss/css files which you can import in this main/styles.css file inside your asset folder. You can import fonts from CDN inside this main css file.

Another way is of course to use style tag inside your vue components

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the import command did work but is showing errors because it tried to locate the resources in vendor.css and couldn't find them

You should also upload your project structure and ensure that there aren't any path issues. Also, you could include the css file in the index.html or the Component template and webpack loader would extract it when built

Comment: I tried placing in `index.html` but it is not finding, I tried `<link rel='stylesheet' href="./src/assets/styles/vendor.css">` but is unable to find. I tried `./assets/styles/vendor.css` i am unable to get

Comment: what they mean by webpack loader is things like `<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />` this says that after compilation by webpack the favicon will be in the root of the output folder (usually dist" you can do simalar with css (see https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) but i wouldn't recommend this as your hardcoding it to a template that supposed to be minimal fuctionality, use one of the other methods instead