# How to change background color of data tables in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to change the background color of my data table as a whole. I don't want to use the dark themed or light themed. I can't seem to change it even when using !important or using available classes.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the relevant color class e.g. `class="primary"` or the name of the color from the vuetify color pack.

`<v-data-table class="elevation-1 primary"></v-data-table>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25849744)

Comment: In vuetify, primary is the name of the primary color in the theme, the class primary sets the background of the element to the color primary. So on the v-data-table component adding the class 'primary' or any of the color names on the vuetify website will set the background color of the data-table to that color. That is exactly what the OP is asking how to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a custom class to `v-data-table` tag like this:

```
<v-data-table ... class="elevation-1 test" ...>
```

*elevation-1* is their standard class name. I added *test* to illustrate the point.

2. Add necessary styling to `.test .theme--light.v-table` selector in your custom CSS.

E.g. `.test .theme--light.v-table { background-color: #00f; }`

You may need to replace the theme name in the CSS path with your theme name.

If you look inside the DOM, you'll notice that class name `test` was applied to a `<div>` container, not the `<table>` element.

[image]

A simple way to include your CSS is with `<style>` tag inside your App.vue file:

```
<style>
  @import './assets/styles/yourstyles.css';
</style>
```

[How to include css files in Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784202/how-to-include-css-files-in-vue-2) has more on that.

Comment: would be nicer to do it on the v-data-table element itself

Answer (score 2):

You can use headers object to specify class as below,

```
headers: [{
    text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
    align: 'start',
    divider: true,
    sortable: false,
    value: 'name',
    class: "blue lighten-5"
},
{
    text: 'Calories',
    value: 'calories',
    align: 'center',
    divider: true,
    class: "blue lighten-5"
}]
```

The above code will add `light blue background` to your header. You can do more with the `class` attr in headers object

Answer (score 0):

The current answers weren't working for my but I found a simple solution. I'll share it just in case anyone sees this in the future.

```
# 1. Add a class to the table element  
<v-simple-table class="table">
...
 </v-simple-table>

# 2. Add background color
<style scoped>
.table {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```