# CSS is not working with vue js on dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created route in vue

```
{
  path: '/coursedetailed/:id',
  component: MyCourseDetailed,
  props: true
},
```

It works, but after I go to the page, it seems that css is disabled. All request are completed component if filled with data. There is one error in console. The other pages works well

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

My vue script for component:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import MenuWhite from '@/components/MenuWhite.vue'

export default {
  name: 'coursedetailed',
  props: ['id'],
  components: {
    MenuWhite
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      course: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData () {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: this.$store.state.endpoints.baseUrl + '/api/courses/' + this.$route.params.id + '/',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
           Authorization: `JWT ${this.$store.state.jwt}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        this.course = response.data
      })
    },
  isToken () {
    if (this.$store.state.jwt) {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/profile' })
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas where the problem may be?

Comment: _"Any ideas where the problem may be?"_.  In your css.

Comment: Search for the `<` character in your component's source code as well as in your css and see if there's a a syntax error. It doesn't seem to be in the code that you posted.

Comment: Could be an unsupported CSS feature, are you using filter()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

As it says, a basic Vue component may have a `template`, a `script` and a `style` tag.

Inside the style tag you may put your css directly or import your css file using the `@import` as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784202/how-to-include-css-files-in-vue-2) by @Geraldine Golong's answer.

So, my suggestion is to put your css code inside your component (if so, recommend you to put inside your parent component), or import your css file using the proper Vue tag.

Hope it helps.