# Bootstrap conflicts with Vuetify date picker

Tags: css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuetify.js

We are creating VueJS/Vuetify components that are placed in an existing website that uses Bootstrap 3.  Vue and Vuetify do not properly scope their CSS to a local scope and instead pollute the global scope.  We have made some changes that seem to over come that issue.  But now, we are seeing something we can't find a solution for. Instead of seeing the Vuetify date picker, we instead see the Bootstrap picker.  Is there a way to force the Vuetify picker to display?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue recently. Most likely you are not using `<v-app>` and `<v-content>` to wrap your app and content respectively.
It is required for some components to display correctly.

[See the docs here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#default-application-markup)

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on idea from here [How to include css files in Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784202/how-to-include-css-files-in-vue-2) helps me

```
<style scoped>
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
</style>
```