# How to load external CSS in Vue

Tags: vue.js, types

I have created a `Vue` project with `Typescript` having components in class style. I need to include some external CSS file - like from `Amazon S3`. The CSS doesn't seems to be loaded.

In the network section I can see it.

[image]

Comment: Can you post how you included the CSS file, And how did you created project ? Did you used `vue-cli` or ?

Comment: Yes I used vue-cli. I included Babel, TS, TSlint, ... I included simply using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` in index.html Updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include css files in Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784202/how-to-include-css-files-in-vue-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can load external URL

```
<style lang="scss or less">
    @import "https://external_url_.css";
    @import ".../assest/_.css";
</style>
```

you can load css loaders installed if you more such as `sass-loader, css-loader , less-loader` npm

Comment: I have installed `"css-loader": "^3.2.0",`
Do I need to configure anywhere.

Comment: not need just tr. if you plan to use less or scss (preprocessor) you can move with preprocessor loader. that's your preference.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use `preprocessor`

Install `SASS` -

```
npm install -D sass-loader sass
```

then You will be able to `import` it in your `App.vue`

```
<style lang="scss">
@import './static/css/style.css';
</style>
```

**Update**

I figured out one more way to include single `css` file.

In your `App.vue`, you can add `css` file to style `src`

```
<style src="relative-path/style.css"></style>
```

Comment: Why I need to use scss here. It's CSS file only ryt

Comment: Correct, but `dynamic` imports requires `scss`.  This way you can even control individual `css` imports to single component too. There is JS way too using webpack but I recommend SASS here neat and helpful. In future you probably want to use scss

Comment: that's optional

Comment: Didn't work for me after installing sass
`<style lang="scss">
  @import url('<some_url>');
</style>`

Comment: Yes I installed sass. I placed the above line in App.vue

Comment: remove `url()` - `sass` doesn't understand that - Give a relative path

Comment: I also updated my answer as I find one more way to do it