# Import css file in Vuepress Vue component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, documentation, vuepress

I am working on a CSS documentation with VuePress, and don't manage to import a .css file into a component.
The website is quite old and there are still differences between desktop, smartphone... so I need to be able to import a precise .css file into a Vue component.

I did this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

@import url('...');

</style>
```

But it doesn't work.
Importing it into the config.js will not allow me to change .css files, and I need to to be able to choose depending upon the component.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load external CSS in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686219/how-to-load-external-css-in-vue)

Comment: @MichalLevý Thanks, two mistakes in my code, first the wrong link... and second, url() not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 errors.

First the wrong link... sorry to not have seen it earlier.

Second, @import '...' is enough, no need of url('').