# How can i import css at Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, import, router

in, Vue package, i want to import css file at all in index.html.

now, 'index.html' > 'App.vue' mount by (#app) > 'Todo.vue' mount by router.

Plz help me, thank you. :)

Comment: where you want to import css in app.js or App.vue ?

Comment: Ddi you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784202/how-to-include-css-files-in-vue-2 (in case you are using vue v2)?

Answer (score 1):

You can import it in `main.js` file.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

This will be available in your all components.